# Is it possible to plot the confidence interval that is out of range in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The sample data is as below:

```
dat = data.frame(estimate = c(1,3,6),conf.low = c(0.5,0.2,0.9), conf.high = c(1.5,3.9,10000), group = as.factor(c(1,2,3)))

#ggplot


dat %>% ggplot(aes(x = group, y = estimate)) +
                 geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high)) +
                 scale_y_continuous(limit = c(0,7),
                                    breaks = c(1:7),
                                    labels = c(1:7)) +
  theme_classic()
```

Is it possible to plot the conf.int (0.9,10000)  without adjusting `limit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say *why* you don't want to change `limit`, but I'm guessing you want to keep the plot view range to (0, 7). You can do this using `coord_carthesian` (note I did remove `limit` from the `scale_y`):

```r
dat %>% ggplot(aes(x = group, y = estimate)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1:7),
                     labels = c(1:7)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 7)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: plot result]

Comment: The reason is that I am writing a function for plotting this type of data. Since the range of confidence interval is not always the same, I need to change the limits of the plot case by case.

Comment: `coord_carthesian` is your friend then, it basically lets you 'use these axis ranges regardless of what the data is' (and does not truncate elements, unlike `limit`).

Comment: I have already applied `coord_carthesian` in my function, what I didn't do is that I didn't delete `limit = c(0,7)` in my function. Thank you for your reminder!^^

Answer (score 1):

How about trying log scale for Y-axis using [`scale_y_log10`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html)?

```r
dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = group, y = estimate)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high)) +
  theme_classic() + 
  scale_y_log10() +
  geom_label(aes(x = group, y = estimate, label = estimate), hjust = -0.5) +
  ylab("estimate (log scale)")
```

Output:

[image]